# Fazer cache de páginas estáticas no browser

Tags: javascript, html, github

Como fazer para que uma página `.html` fique em cache do navegador por um período de 20 minutos após ela ser baixada?

**Obs:** A Página é estática e não existe um "Back-end" é tudo feito com `HTML`, `CSS` e `JS`, esta hospedado no subdominio `.github.io`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traduzindo desta resposta [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15122268/1518921)

> Eu perguntei aos administradores do GitHub e eles me disseram que *"não é possível"* alterar o *headers* da resposta HTTP nas página *github.io*.
>
> Eles adicionaram está solicitação a *wishlist* (algo que pode ser ou não feito em uma futura atualização).

Portanto somente os administradores do Github conseguem controlar isto.

### Pontos adicionais

Note que algumas pessoas afirmam que a tag `<meta>` pode fazer um cache da página, mas acredito que tais tags sejam usadas apenas para os *bots* (como o do Google, corrija-me se eu estiver enganado).