# Como resolver problema de Cache do Google?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, cache, google-analytics-api

Fiz o teste no *pagespeed* e mesmo ja tendo instalado o *plugin* do Wordpress apareceu isso:

> Leverage browser caching
>   Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded resources from local disk rather than over the network.
>   Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>
> http://maps.googleapis.com/…libraries=places&language=en&key&ver=1.0 (30 minutes)
>
> http://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-963.min.js (60 minutes)
>
> http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Se os links forem seus então você pode tentar configurar usando `.htaccess` (se usar apache) como respondi em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120344/3635
- Se for uma página do github.io não tem como (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67190/3635)
- Se forem links externos, os quais você não tem controle sobre os servidores, como maps.google.com e googleanalitics não há o que fazer

  > todavia se forem imagens talvez você possar usar um proxy em uma linguagem de programação, vai depender da necessidade do uso da imagem, um exemplo com php: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124656/3635

Resumindo, faça o melhor que der, alguns links de serviços essenciais infelizmente não irão dar o 100/100 ou 99/100 no pagespeed, mas é algo supérfluo. Concentresse em reduzir apenas as requisições no teu servidor e chamar APIs de terceiros somente quando necessário.

**Por exemplo**, acredito que não vá usar google-maps em todas páginas, então só chame isto `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>` nas páginas necessárias.

Comment: Ok Guilherme irei testar, obrigado!